# Monitor Java web-app using Prometheus

Tags: java, monitoring, prometheus

I got a simple java web application running on Tomcat which I would like to monitor using [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/).
I added some counters and gauges to my java app using [the official client](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java), I installed Prometheus on another server and not would like to pull the metrics from my java app using Prometheus.

Prometheus got [tons of exporters](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/) but I'm not clear about which one fits my use case.
I considered using [Prometheus push gateway](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway) but according to the [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/) the only valid use case for the Pushgateway is for capturing the outcome of a service-level batch job, which is not my case.
What should I do in order to pull the metrics from my java app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to register MetricsServlet:

If you are using spring-boot register a bean to represent the end-point:

```
@Bean
ServletRegistrationBean registerPrometheusExporterServlet(CollectorRegistry metricRegistry) {
    ServletRegistrationBean srb = new ServletRegistrationBean();
    srb.setServlet(new MetricsServlet(metricRegistry));
    srb.setUrlMappings(Arrays.asList("/prometheus"));
    return srb;
}
```

In case of a non-spring app add the servlet in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>metrics</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>io.prometheus.client.exporter.MetricsServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>metrics</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/metrics/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Hi, @forhas Is this ServletRegistrationBean enough? Do we need to call it when we create custom Gauge metrics, for example.
Can you help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72629611/how-to-redirect-prometheus-metrics-to-the-default-spring-boot-server

Answer (score 3):

You should have your application expose the metrics over HTTP. You probably want to hook the [servlet](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java#http) into your existing webserver.

Comment: @forhas : servlet is container-neutral